# Swipeable screen with content inside webView

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I have a screen with recyclerView and articles list inside it. After clicking on item - i open new activity with content inside WebView (each article has own url which is displayed). I need to improve this functionality and add ability to switch between articles inside my activity with WebView by swipe movement (left - right). 
That is my question: which way should i choose, make it with ViewPager or intercept swipe moves manually and refresh only content for WebView. Which way would be better for performance and more friendly user? Maybe some of you already have this experience?

Comment: Hi. Do not multiple webviews with native viewpager. Use only one. One way is to create swipe listener. Another create a js/html analog of viewpager.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you know how to manage with pre caching of pages?